# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at RegistrarUsuario con React y firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

estoy haciendo un sistema para registrar un usuario usando react y firebase, pero al momento de mandar los datos usando hooks, pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que utilizo para registrar el usuario es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import '../css/login.css'
import {auth} from '../firebaseconfig'

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [pass, setPass] = useState('')

    const RegistrarUsuario = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()

        try{
            auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={RegistrarUsuario} action="">

            <input onChange={(e)=>{setEmail(e.target.value)}} type="text"  placeholder="Email"/>
            <input onChange={(e)=>{setPass(e.target.value)}}type="password" name="" id="" placeholder="********"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Continuar" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Y la configuracion de firebase es asi:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x-x.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "x-x",
  storageBucket: "x-x.x.com",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "1:x",
  measurementId: "G-x"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = getAuth(app);

export { auth }
```

Estuve investigando y leyendo mucho, pero casi todo lo que encuentro es haciendo uso de Angular y yo soy un aprendiz, no se si esas soluciones podrian arruinar mi codigo, por eso prefiero optar por escribir aca.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano

Comment: Le sobran los paréntesis a `auth()`. Como dice claramente el mensaje, ese objeto no es una función. Debería ser simplemente `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)`

Comment: Pero si no le pongo los paréntesis me salía otro error